# The end iterator for a linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I started to implement a list and got stuck at the `end()` iterator function. My understanding is that `end()` should point one element after the last member of the list. But since in a list elements are not contiguous in memory how can we point to one position after the last one?

And one extra question, how can we have `operator--`? If previous element points to current one, so current one do not have the knowledge about the previous.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(const T _value) : value(_value) {}

    T value;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> next = nullptr;
};

template<typename T>
class List
{
public:

    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        Iterator(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> node) : m_node(node) {}

        T& operator*()
        {
            return m_node->value;
        }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> m_node;
    };

    void insert_back(const T value)
    {
        auto node = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value);

        if (!m_node)
            m_node = node;
        else
        {
            node->next = m_node;
            m_node = node;
        }
    }

    Iterator begin()
    {
        if (!m_node)
            return Iterator(nullptr);

        auto node = m_node;
        while(node->next)
            node = node->next;

        Iterator it(node);
        return it;
    }

    // Iterator end(){} // ?

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> m_node = nullptr;
};

void test()
{
    List<int> list;

    list.insert_back(4);
    list.insert_back(2);

    auto beg = list.begin();
    std::cout << "beg is: " << *beg << std::endl;

    // auto end = list.end();
    // std::cout << "end is: " << *end << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "starting..." << std::endl;

    test();

}
```

Comment: *end() should point one element after the last member of the list* - There is no such a requirement in general. Your `end` iterator could be e.g. `Iterator(nullptr)`.

Comment: Also note that `begin()` and `end()` should have `O(1)` time complexity by convention. Your implementation violates this.

Comment: The only real requirement for _ForwardIterator_ is that the end-iterator is not equal to any iterators referencing items actually in your list. However you achieve that, provided the behavior is defined, is up to you. For lists, the obvious choice is a `nullptr`, but it would be just as valid to store a pointer to some static "empty" iterator, or add a flag to the iterator marking it as special without even initializing the pointer. Of course, for lists none of that would make practical sense.

Comment: Side-note: Using `std::shared_ptr` for iterators seems like overkill. Iterators are not required to extend the lifetime of values, and it would be quite unexpected if they do.

Comment: Any real implementation of a linked list shouldn't use smart pointers in the way this question demonstrates. There is a risk of stack overflow in the list's destructor.

Comment: "Past the end" is conceptual, not literal. A pair of iterators defines a range; when the first iterator compares equal to the second iterator you're at the end of the range. To get there, the first iterator pointed at the last element in the range, and then was incremented to "past the end".

Comment: @Evg in order to make that happen I need to keep another private/member node, in addition to m_node? Should we call them head and tail then? And head will be the begin while end will point one past the tail? With all that insert_back() will insert at the tail?

Comment: If it's a singly linked list, `insert_back` is `O(N)` and `insert_front` is `O(1)` - `m_node` keeps the first node, not the last. Then `begin()` simply returns an iterator to `m_node`.

Comment: Got it! Another thing is the `operator--`, I edited the question to mention I'm not sure about it.

Comment: The answer is simple - for a singly-linked list we can't have `operator--` just for the reason you described. That's why we have forward and bidirectional iterators in the standard library. Forward iterators only have `operator++`. To go backwards, you need a doubly linked list (cf. `std::list` and `std::forward_list`).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably if you reach a `nullptr` you have reached the end of the list, so:

```
Iterator end() {
    return Iterator(nullptr);
}
```

You probably also want `Node` to be *inside* of `List` as no user of `List` should need to directly create or modify a `Node`.

As a nitpick, `m_node` in `List` is probably better named `head`, `head_node`, or something to that effect.

Comment: 1) Actually the iterator is not null, dereferencing it will result in null (am I wrong on my thoughts?); 2) At https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator I can't read "iterators can't be null", do you have a reference where I can read more about it?

Comment: @KcFnMi - I was thinking of std::list, not std::forward_list. An iterator to std::list::end() can be decremented to point to the last node of a list, so std::list::end() isn't null. I deleted my prior comments and will delete this one later.

Answer (score 2):

The end iterator should *logically* refer to "one past the end", but it doesn't have to *physically* refer to anything.  The only requirement is that it compares equal to the iterator value you obtain by incrementing an iterator that refers to the last element of the list.

In the case of your `List` class, the last node in the list has a null `next` pointer, so when you increment an iterator to that node you'll end up with an iterator holding a null pointer.  That means your `end` iterator can simply be

```
Iterator end() {
    return Iterator(nullptr);
}
```

Comment: @rcgldr An iterator for `std::list` can't be a raw pointer. This can only be true for contiguous containers, `std::vector` and `std::array`.

Comment: @Evg - I deleted my prior comments and will delete this one later. Visual Studio release build uses unchecked pointers for std::list::iterator. std::list::end points to a head node with a data value of 0 (or null) which allows std::list::end() to be dereferenced (in a release build, debug build will check for this). The head node is between the last and first nodes of a circular doubly-linked list.

Comment: @rcgldr And for a doubly-linked list that is the normal way to implement this (and it cannot hold just a `nullptr` because you need to be able to decrement it, e.g. `back() == *--end()`). For a singly-linked list (`std::forward_list`), it does hold a nullptr: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1bc5ca60fcb41c2ed87a721d6ca2f77844cf6dc6/stl/inc/forward_list#L806 (the second argument is the allocator)

Comment: @Artyer - I think that in the case of GCC,instead of a head node, it uses a sub-node with just previous and next pointers, but no data member, so it can't be dereferenced. Visual Studio uses a normal node for the head node and with a release build, it can be dereferenced (since it is an unchecked pointer).

Answer (score -1):

The main purpose of implementing iterators is to **iterate** your collection and `::begin()` and `end()` functions are intended to help you in that purpose. So basically `::begin()` and `::end()` give you the range including all the elements in the collection so you can use for example a `for` loop to iterate your collection, typically using the `++` operator to get the next element, something like this:

`for (auto it = my_list.begin(); it != my_list.end(); ++it) { show *it; }`.

Since `::end()` points to the *past-the-end* element, this ensures you listed all the elements in the loop.

Now regarding to your specific question about how does the `::end()` function points to "one position after last element", the answer is: it will depend on the data structure of your collection. In your case and according your code, you want to implement a simple unidirectional linked list, so what I would do  is to create a special node `end_node` that represents the *past-the-end* element and always making sure that the `<last item>->next` points to `end_node`.

Here is a sightly modified version of your code implementing this idea, please take into account the code could have bugs or performance issues, it is just to illustrate the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(const T _value) : value(_value) {}

    T value;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> next = nullptr;
};

template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List() : m_root_node(std::make_shared<Node<T>>(T())), m_end_node(std::make_shared<Node<T>>(T()))
    {
        m_root_node->next = m_end_node;
    }

    class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>>
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> m_p;
        public:
          Iterator(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> p) : m_p(p) { }
          Iterator(const Iterator& it) : m_p(it.m_p) { }
          Iterator& operator++() { m_p = m_p->next; return *this; }
          Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp; }
          bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) const { return m_p == rhs.m_p; }
          bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) const { return m_p != rhs.m_p; }
          int& operator*() { return m_p->value; }
    };

    void insert_back(const T value)
    {
        auto new_end_node = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(T());
        m_end_node->value = value; // end node becomes the last item
        m_end_node->next = new_end_node; // last item->next always points to the end node
        m_end_node = new_end_node; // moving end node to the end
    }

    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(m_root_node->next);
    }

    Iterator end()
    {
        return Iterator(m_end_node);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> m_root_node; // helps to track the first element, useful when you want to implement insert_front
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> m_end_node; // helps to track the last element, useful to insert elements at the end without looping
};

void test()
{
    List<int> list;

    list.insert_back(4);
    list.insert_back(2);
    list.insert_back(3);

    auto beg = list.begin();
    std::cout << "beg is: " << *beg << std::endl;

    auto end = list.end();
    std::cout << "end is: " << *end << std::endl;
    
    for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "item: " << *it << ", ";
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    auto it = list.begin();
    
    while (it != list.end())
    {
        std::cout << "item: " << *it << ", ";
        it++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "starting..." << std::endl;

    test();
}
```

Comment: I think I read somewhere we should not derive from std::iterator, isn't?

Comment: @KcFnMi Correct. `std::iterator` was deprecated in C++17. Don't use it.